# How to load 3D .obj model in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am the three.js beginner. I created 3D obj model file in three.js. How to the object(3D .obj) return to another function? and How to original colour visible .obj 3D?

> Javascript

```
this.draw3DObj = function (startX, startY, endX, endY, objType) {
    switch (objType) {
     case "window":
      var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
       color: 0xbcb9b1,
       side: THREE.DoubleSide
      });
      loader.load('model/window.obj', function(object) {
        object.traverse(function(child) {

         if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          child.material = material;
         }

        });
        scene1.add(object);
        object.position.x = width;
        object.position.y = depth;
        object.position.z = height;
       },

       function(xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
       },

       function(error) {
        console.log('An error happened');
       }
      );
      break;
    }
    return object; // How to return?
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly return the object, because the loading as asynchronous. The first argument passed to `loader.load` is a callback that gets called when the object is loaded. At the end of that function you can call another function and pass the object.

Comment: How to return my 3D scene, camera, render created in another js file. so how to return this 3D obj value? @mbuechmann

Comment: You cannot return it from `draw3DObj`. The function `draw3DObj` exits before the first callback finishes. An idea would be to use promises.

If you want to read up on sync/async look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

If you want to read up on promises look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises